# Avoiding Office Online's "...wants to display a new window."

Tags: office-js

I'm using `Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync`. When I click a button in the ribbon from Office Online, I get a modal from Office Online titled "Notification" asking for permission with the text "{addin} wants to display a new window".

How can I make this stop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Passing `displayInIframe: true` to the dialog options will suppress the message.

Comment: Didn't work for me at all, and then I discovered this note in the Microsoft documentation:

You should not use displayInIframe: true if the dialog will at any point redirect to a page that cannot be opened in an iframe. For example, the sign in pages of many popular web services, such as Google and Microsoft Account, cannot be opened in an iframe.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open a new window from the ribbon button, then this notification dialog is needed. Otherwise, your new window will be clocked by the browser popup blocker. This is a design for displayDialogAsync api. But also as Daniel said, you can just pass the displayInIframe:true to open a inline iframe dialog from the ribbon button, in this case, there is no notification for it.

Comment: In my case, I am trying to open a dialog for SSO with Microsoft from a ribbon button.  The Microsoft SSO page cannot be displayed in an Iframe.  Is there another way, besides using displayInIframe:true, that will avoid the modal that asks for permission to open the window?

Comment: The Microsoft office team is working to add another parameter to the displayDialogAsync api. With this parameter, developer can decide whether they need this notification to be shown or not. The implementation has not been deployed to prod environment yet. So you may need to wait for it. After it deployed to prod environment, we will update this doc(https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/officeui.displaydialogasync?product=access) about how to use it.